# can I programmatically import/export a fusion table

Tags: google-fusion-tables

We can export a fusion table as a CSV file using File > Download (https://support.google.com/fusiontables/answer/2548807?hl=en&ref_topic=27017)

I need to set up a script to import and export CSV data from SQL on a timer. Is there a way to do it programmatically (Java/Javascript/Python)?

I have found some examples using php that may work. It seems like it should be a common task. Am I looking at the problem wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Fusion Tables API to import:
https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v1/reference/table/importRows

Comment: Thanks  I am looking for how to export also.  I am not sure I am going about it the right way. It seems harder than it should for a common task.

Answer (score 1):

To export data as CSV from a Fusion Table you can make a SELECT query with the query parameter alt=csv

https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/query?alt=csv&sql=SELECT ROW1, ROW2, ROW3 FROM 1e7y6mtqv892222222222_bbbbbbbbb_CvWhg9gc

https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v1/using#query-params